# STL Static-Const Member Definitions

Tags: c++, static, constants, definition, linkage

How does the following work?

```
#include <limits>

int main()
{
  const int* const foo = &std::numeric_limits<int> ::digits;
}
```

I was under the impression that in order to take an address of a `static const`-ant member we had to physically define it in some translation unit in order to please the linker. That said, after looking at the preprocessed code for this TU, I couldn't find an external definition for the `digits` member (or any other relevant members).

I tested this on two compilers (VC++ 10 and g++ 4.2.4) and got identical results from both (i.e., it works). Does the linker auto-magically link against an object file where this stuff is defined, or am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, what makes you think that it is *not* defined? The very fact that your attempt to take the address succeeded automatically indicates that it *is* defined somewhere. It is not required to reside in your tranlation unit, of course, so looking through the preprocessor output doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Well, two things: 1) I thought that the limits header might be bringing it in to my translation unit. Doesn't seem to be the case. 2) I looked at VS's linker command line and couldn't find any "foreign" object files being implicitly specified.

Comment: @javery: Foreign? Why foreign? The definition must be a part of the Standard Library. You *are* linking with standard library, aren't you?

Comment: By "foreign" I meant foreign to my own files; that includes the standard library. Sorry for the confusion. :)

Comment: @javery: Your code *includes* stanadard header files only. The "meat" of the Standard Library resides in... well... in a *library*, which is normally linked into your project implicitly.

Comment: Found it. Like you said, implicitly linked. Was confused because it wasn't explicitly listed as an additional dependency anywhere. Cheers.